# preg-match date in 1 Jan 2001 format

Tags: php, regex, date, preg-match

I'm wish to remove all content in a string after this phrase in PHP:

```
On 17 Mar 2015
```

How would I match any date?

EDIT: I use this currently to remove the phrase and all content after it in a string:

```
if (strpos($body,"On 17 Mar 2015") !== false) { $body = substr($body, 0, strpos($body, "On 17 Mar 2015"));}
```

Input =

```
reply reply reply reply reply reply reply reply 

On 17 Mar 2015, at 10:23, user wrote:

> email email email email email email email email email email email email 
> email email email email email email email email email email email email
```

Expected output:

```
reply reply reply reply reply reply reply reply
```

for any possible date

Comment: Whats your expected output? did you want to match or remove?

Comment: So do you want to remove all content after this phrase or do you want to match a date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the format of the phrase doesn't change, the regular expression below should do the trick for any date possible.

```
$phrase = "On 17 Mar 2015";
preg_match("#(?<=On\s)\d+\s\w+\s\d+#", $phrase, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

Comment: How would I match any date?

Comment: @MikeThrussell Did you give it a go? You can change the date in the variable `$phrase`. It's going to match it.

Comment: My apologies I misunderstood the code. This works great, thanks

Comment: @MikeThrussell Perfect, have fun.